# How the salinity of the North Atlantic is changing

Tags: climate-change, arctic

The Arctic has lost 3.6 million km^2 of sea ice due to climate change. This is also referred to as freshening. Are there any studies focussing on the development of the salinity of the North Atlantic?

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for:https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-14474-y